# How to alternate colors based on first column of google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

So I have a spread sheet that has a bunch of data in it... The first column is the state, second is a name. What I want to do is have the rows alternate blue/red/blue/red (to make it easy to read) but I don't want it to alternate EVERY row like evens/odds. What I want is for each state to have a different color. So all the rows with AL blue, then CA red, CT blue, etc... This is just a basic example. Obviously here I could just hardcode the 50 states, but is there any way to automate this process so that basically every time the state changes, I switch colors?

```
State    Name
AL       John
CA       Bill
CA       Joe
CA       Chad
CT       Mary
VA       Beth
VA       Dani
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Google Sheets you can count how many unique names there are down to the current cell and test if it's an odd number

```
=isodd(countunique(A$2:A2))
```

Apply this to the range as a custom formula in conditional formats with the first fill colour.

Then apply

```
=iseven(countunique(A$2:A2))
```

as another rule with the second fill colour.

In Excel it's more difficult to do this, would end up with something like

```
=ISODD(SUM(--(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A$2:A2,A$2:A2,0),MATCH(A$2:A2,A$2:A2,0))>0)))
```

and

```
=ISEVEN(SUM(--(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A$2:A2,A$2:A2,0),MATCH(A$2:A2,A$2:A2,0))>0)))
```

*Note* this only works if the data is sorted by state as in your test data.

Comment: Is it possible to expand this to format the entire row's color based in this? This solution works perfectly for formatting just the state's cell.

Comment: Yes, if you fix the column with dollar signs e.g. =isodd(countunique($A$2:$A2))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Format as a table` with the following procedure:

- Open the worksheet.
- Select the cell range that you want to shade, or
  press Ctrl+A to select the whole worksheet.
- Click the Home tab.
- In the Styles group, click Format as Table, and then click the style of
  formatting that you want.
- In the Format as Table dialog box, click OK.

Also, as an alternative you can use `Conditional Formatting`.